# Retrive child objects using sdk in sap bo?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I am trying to write a code to change report ownership. I need to retrieve all the child objects of a parent object. How to do it using the java sdk or query?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the infoobject ID of the folder, it's easy:

`select * from ci_infoobjects where si_parentid = x`

`x` being the ID of the folder